# Match characters across line in different blocks in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Suppose I have a text file like below:

```
Block 1 start
Line 1 in Block 1
Line 2 in Block 1
Block 1 end

Block 2 start
Line 1 in Block 2

Block 3 start
Line 1 in Block 3
Block 3 end
```

How can I select Block 1 and Block 3 (start and end lines inclusive) and skip the two lines of Blocks 2 in Sublime?

Comment: Does Block 2 not have a `Block 2 end` line?

Comment: No, it doesn't have that line

Comment: Did you try anything? What is the logic for block 1 and block 3 so that block 2 should not be matched?

Comment: I tried regex but I failed. The regex I wrote can't skip the two lines in Block 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?s)Block (\d+) start.+Block \1 end
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/ojROl3/1)

```
(?s)              - basically a multiline modifier. Allows the `.` to match newlines.
Block (\d+) start - Matches the start of a block
.+                - Capture everything inside the block
Block \1 end      - Finds the end of the block by using the number found at the beginning in the Block start section.(back referencing)
```

This should work for cases where you want to skip blocks that don't have a valid end section.

If the data isn't well formatted, then you will run into issues. For an example if something like `Block 1 end` happens to be inside the block.